# Keeping dimensional consistency on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, dimensions

I am working on a very simplistic website right now to keep consistency between screens fairly precise.

My problem though, is that for some reason on phone browsers the content on the website appears to be zoomed out and much smaller than it is supposed to be.

I'm using `ems` for measuring and trying to use this unit as a way to keep the dimensions consistent between screens, but I think I'm using them incorrectly or I need to figure out a different way.

Here's my jsfiddle for a basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/szzmc71f/

P.S: I'm trying to achieve this consistency based on scale.

Comment: Add a [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Comment: That seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I went ahead and added that as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [**viewport**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) to the document in order to achieve this consistency:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```